# Handling Image pointer to pointer in CUDA

Tags: c, pointers, image-processing, cuda, fractals

I have been trying to put in place a CUDA code (taken in part from Fractal Image Compression by Yuval Fisher) that has a double pointer to a 2D image. After taking care of the pointer to pointer allocation in [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15113960/cuda-allocating-array-of-pointers-to-images-and-the-images/15115362#15115362/) , I am still getting segmentation fault error along with **"Warning: Cannot tell what pointer points to, assuming global memory space"** warning. Here is the entire [**code**](https://gist.github.com/codestamp/11153860). I am also posting it here as under: (My apologies for duplicating the posted code)

```
#include <cuda.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define hsize 256
#define vsize 256

#define IMAGE_TYPE unsigned char


__global__ void kernel(IMAGE_TYPE matrixin[][hsize], IMAGE_TYPE matrixout[][hsize]) {
int tid=threadIdx.x;
int bid=blockIdx.x;

matrixout[bid][tid]=matrixin[bid][tid];
}

int fatal(char* s) {
fprintf(stderr,"%s\n",s);
return 1;
}

#define matrix_allocate(matrix,hsize,vsize,TYPE) {\
    TYPE *imptr;\
    int _i;\
    matrix=(TYPE**)malloc((vsize)*sizeof(TYPE*));\
    imptr=(TYPE*)malloc((long)(hsize)*(long)(vsize)*sizeof(TYPE));\
    if(imptr==NULL)\
    fatal("\nNo memory in matrix allocate.");\
    for(_i=0;_i<vsize;++_i,imptr+=hsize)\
    matrix[_i] = imptr;\
}\


int main() {
typedef IMAGE_TYPE IMarray[vsize][hsize];
IMAGE_TYPE **hin_image,**hout_image;

IMarray *din_image,*dout_image;


//allocate host memory
matrix_allocate(hin_image,hsize,vsize,IMAGE_TYPE)
for(int i=0;i<vsize;i++)
    for(int j=0;j<hsize;j++)
        hin_image[i][j]='a';

matrix_allocate(hout_image,hsize,vsize,IMAGE_TYPE)


//allocate device memory

cudaMalloc((void**)&din_image,(vsize*hsize)*sizeof(IMAGE_TYPE));
cudaMalloc((void**)&dout_image,(vsize*hsize)*sizeof(IMAGE_TYPE));

cudaMemcpy(din_image,hin_image, (vsize*hsize)*sizeof(IMAGE_TYPE),cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

dim3 threads(hsize,1,1);
dim3 blocks(vsize,1,1);

kernel<<<blocks,threads>>>(din_image,dout_image);

cudaMemcpy(hout_image,dout_image,(vsize*hsize)*sizeof(IMAGE_TYPE),cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

for(int i=0;i<10;i++) {
    printf("\n");
    for(int j=0;j<10;j++)
        printf("%c\t",hout_image[i][j]);
}
printf("\n");

cudaFree(din_image);
cudaFree(dout_image);

free(hin_image);
free(hout_image);

return 0;
}
```

I intend to know what is wrong with the standard 2D access of image inside the kernel function. Any help would be highly welcome.

Comment: You are looking in the wrong place for the problem. A kernel will *never* cause a segmentation fault in host code. My guess is that your  host memory management is broken somehow and you are hosing the stack with a buffer overflow somewhere. I see valgrind and/or a host debugger in your immediate future..........

Comment: Your code is so wrong. Why are you copying `hd_imageout` into `dd_imageont` knowing that `dd_imageout` and `hd_imageout` are on the GPU. You are not freeing correctly `hd_imageout` neither `hh_imageout` neither `hh_imagein`...And same thing for the `[...]in` ptr... I think you shouldn't mix the ptr on the host and the ptr on the GPU, you are doing wrong..

Comment: Since you know the dimension (width) of your array at compile time, you can use some `typedef`s to allow you to access a multidimensional array in a kernel but pass only a single pointer (`*`).  [This code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14920931/3d-cuda-kernel-indexing-for-image-filtering/14926201#14926201) gives an example.

Comment: @RobertCrovella: Many thanks for the input. I modified the [code](https://gist.github.com/codestamp/11240936) according to the link you have given in your post. I get the error "error: argument of type "IMarray *" is incompatible with parameter of type "unsigned char (*)[256]". I think this is due to the incompatibility on the parameters of the kernel call. I have edited the code in my main comment to highlight it.

Comment: Yes, you're still not grasping what is going on.   I posted an answer with code that compiles and runs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not going to try and sort out your complex matrix allocation scheme.  The purpose of my suggestion was so that you can simplify things to simple 1-line allocations.

Furthermore, I don't think you really grasped the example I gave.  It was a 3D example, and the typedefs had 2 subscripts.  A 2D version would have typedefs with a single subscript.

Really none of this has to do with CUDA.  It revolves around understanding of C arrays and pointers.

Those were the major changes I made to get your code working:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define hsize 256
#define vsize 256

#define IMAGE_TYPE unsigned char


__global__ void kernel(IMAGE_TYPE matrixin[][hsize], IMAGE_TYPE matrixout[][hsize]) {
  int tid=threadIdx.x;
  int bid=blockIdx.x;

  matrixout[bid][tid]=matrixin[bid][tid];
}

int fatal(char* s) {
  fprintf(stderr,"%s\n",s);
  return 1;
}


int main() {
  typedef IMAGE_TYPE IMarray[hsize];
  IMarray *hin_image,*hout_image;

  IMarray *din_image,*dout_image;


//allocate host memory
  hin_image = (IMarray *)malloc(hsize*vsize*sizeof(IMAGE_TYPE));
  hout_image = (IMarray *)malloc(hsize*vsize*sizeof(IMAGE_TYPE));

  for(int i=0;i<vsize;i++)
    for(int j=0;j<hsize;j++)
        hin_image[i][j]='a';


//allocate device memory

  cudaMalloc((void**)&din_image,(vsize*hsize)*sizeof(IMAGE_TYPE));
  cudaMalloc((void**)&dout_image,(vsize*hsize)*sizeof(IMAGE_TYPE));
  cudaMemset(dout_image, 0, (vsize*hsize)*sizeof(IMAGE_TYPE));
  cudaMemcpy(din_image,hin_image, (vsize*hsize)*sizeof(IMAGE_TYPE),cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

  dim3 threads(hsize,1,1);
  dim3 blocks(vsize,1,1);

  kernel<<<blocks,threads>>>(din_image,dout_image);

  cudaMemcpy(hout_image,dout_image,(vsize*hsize)*sizeof(IMAGE_TYPE),cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

  for(int i=0;i<10;i++) {
    printf("\n");
    for(int j=0;j<10;j++)
        printf("%c\t",hout_image[i][j]);
  }
  printf("\n");

  cudaFree(din_image);
  cudaFree(dout_image);

  free(hin_image);
  free(hout_image);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I agree I need to work on my C skills. The code is working now.