# How to use pointer to pointer in cuda

Tags: pointers, cuda, malloc

I have a problem with using of pointer to pointer in cuda.
Code snippet is below.

```
char** d_ppcPtr, *d_pcPtr, *h_pcPtr;
cudaMalloc(&d_ppcPtr, sizeof(char*) * 10);

h_pcPtr = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * 100);
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i ++)
{
      cudaMalloc(&d_pcPtr, sizeof(char) * 100);
      cudaMemset(d_pcPtr, 1, sizeof(char) * 100);
      cudaMemcpy(&d_ppcPtr[i], &d_pcPtr, sizeof(char*), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
      cudaMemcpy(h_pcPtr, d_ppcPtr[i], sizeof(char) * 100, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost); //crash here
      cudaFree(d_ppcPtr[i]); //crash also here
}
cudaFree(d_ppcPtr);
```

how can i fix above two crashes?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What kind of crash? Segfault? Error messages?

Comment: access violation reading at d_ppcPtr[i] address.

Comment: Have you allocated the memory space to which `d_ppcPtr[i]` is supposed to point?

Comment: from cudaMalloc(&d_ppcPtr, sizeof(char*) * 10);
d_ppcPtr[i] is initiated and it's value is assigned from the line
cudaMemcpy(&d_ppcPtr[i], &d_pcPtr, sizeof(char*), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
besides watching and freeing, this pointer works well

Comment: please refer to this link 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15113960/cuda-allocating-array-of-pointers-to-images-and-the-images

Comment: The pointers used as arguments of `cudaMemcpy` should physically reside on the host, while `d_ppcPtr[i]` resides on the device.

Comment: @JackOLantern, have you seen the link i offered?
At there, Rovert Crovella answered like me and also it(d_ppcPtr[i]) works good in device code, but not in host code.
This is what i want to know.

Comment: There is a difference between your code and that by Robert Crovella in the answer to the post you have linked to. There, `temp[i]` is a pointer that resides on the host and that points to a device memory space. Here, `d_ppcPtr[i]` resides on the device.

Comment: Here, what is corresponding to temp[i] at here? It's just d_pcPtr, not d_ppcPtr[i].

Comment: i can't enter chat room due to my low reputation, Sorry Jack

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following modification will "fix" your code (fully worked example, including host and device verification):

```
$ cat t583.cu
#include <stdio.h>

__global__ void testkernel(char **data, unsigned n){
  for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) if (data[n][i] != 1) printf("kernel error\n");
}

int main(){
  char** d_ppcPtr, *d_pcPtr, *h_pcPtr;
  cudaMalloc(&d_ppcPtr, sizeof(char*) * 10);

  h_pcPtr = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * 100);
  for(int i = 0; i < 10; i ++)
  {
      cudaMalloc(&d_pcPtr, sizeof(char) * 100);
      cudaMemset(d_pcPtr, 1, sizeof(char) * 100);
      cudaMemcpy(&d_ppcPtr[i], &d_pcPtr, sizeof(char*), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
      memset(h_pcPtr, 0, sizeof(char)*100);
      testkernel<<<1,1>>>(d_ppcPtr, i);
      cudaMemcpy(h_pcPtr, d_pcPtr, sizeof(char) * 100, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
      cudaFree(d_pcPtr);
      for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) if (h_pcPtr[i] != 1) printf("Error!");
  }
  cudaFree(d_ppcPtr);
}
$ nvcc -arch=sm_20 -o t583 t583.cu
$ cuda-memcheck ./t583
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
```

Note that conceptually, there is no difference between my code and yours, because the pointer that you are attempting to use in location `d_ppcPtr[i]`, (and is crashing, because it is located on the device,) is already contained in `d_pcPtr`, which is on the host.

Comment: Thank you so much, Robert Crovella.
Explicit answer!

Comment: Shouldn't `cudaMemcpy(&d_ppcPtr[i], &d_pcPtr, sizeof(char*), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);` use `cudaMemcpyDeviceToDevice`? Both d_ppcPtr and d_pcPtr were `cudaMalloc`ed, which means they're both on the device. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, you are missing something,  `d_pcPtr` was indeed `cudaMalloc`ed, but the transfer here is not from `d_pcPtr` but from `&d_pcPtr`, which I guarantee you is a host pointer.  If the transfer direction were wrong, `cuda-memcheck` would have also spit out an error.  If this is not clear, let's not try to sort it out here in the comments.  Feel free to experiment with it yourself.  This is a deep-copy operation, which you may not be grasping.