# How to Optimize CUDA Sieve of Eratosthenes

Tags: c, cuda, sieve-of-eratosthenes

I'm new to CUDA.  To get my hands dirty, I tried writing a Sieve of Eratosthenes (for finding all the primes up to some number n).

There are a number of things I had to do to get it to work that it seems shouldn't have been necessary.  I'm curious whether anyone knows of a more natural (and still CUDA-optimized) approach.

1. To take the entries marked as prime in the isPrime array, I had to do two separate kernel calls. The first counts the number of primes in each threadblock and assigns to each entry i the number of primes in that block less than i. Then I have to make a second call to add in the number of primes in all the previous blocks in order to get the final index.
2. But it's even worse than that, because to avoid heaps of concurrent reads, I had to store the number of primes in the block in a separate array at each of THREADS_PER_BLOCK indices effectively doubling the required memory for the algorithm.  It seems like there should be a way to have all the threads read the same value for each block rather than have to copy it so many times.
3. Despite all this, there's still the problem of concurrent reads in the clearMultiples method.  Especially for small primes like 2 and 3, every thread has to read the value in.  Isn't there any way to deal with this?

Could anyone look at my code and tell me if there's anything obvious I could do that would be simpler or more efficient?

Is there anything I'm doing that's particularly inefficient (besides printing out all the primes at the end of course)?

Is it necessary to call synchronize after every kernel call?

Do I need to synchronize after memcpy's as well?

Finally, how come when I set THREADS_PER_BLOCK to 512 it doesn't work?

Thank you

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cuda.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <math.h>

#define MAX_BLOCKS 256
#define THREADS_PER_BLOCK 256 //Must be a power of 2
#define BLOCK_SPACE 2 * THREADS_PER_BLOCK

__global__ void initialize(int* isPrime, int n) {
    int idx = blockIdx.x * THREADS_PER_BLOCK + threadIdx.x;
    int step = gridDim.x * THREADS_PER_BLOCK;
    int i;
    for (i = idx; i <= 1; i += step) {
        isPrime[i] = 0;
    }
    for (; i < n; i += step) {
        isPrime[i] = 1;
    }
}

__global__ void clearMultiples(int* isPrime, int* primeList, int startInd,
        int endInd, int n) {
    int yidx = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
    int xidx = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    int ystep = gridDim.y * blockDim.y;
    int xstep = gridDim.x * blockDim.x;
    for (int pnum = startInd + yidx; pnum < endInd; pnum += ystep) {
        int p = primeList[pnum];
        int pstart = p * (p + xidx);
        int pstep = p * xstep;
        for (int i = pstart; i < n; i += pstep) {
            isPrime[i] = 0;
        }
    }
}

__device__ void makeCounts(int* isPrime, int* addend, int start, int stop) {
    __shared__ int tmpCounts[BLOCK_SPACE];
    __shared__ int dumbCounts[BLOCK_SPACE];
    int idx = threadIdx.x;
    tmpCounts[idx] = ((start + idx) < stop) ? isPrime[start + idx] : 0;
    __syncthreads();
    int numEntries = THREADS_PER_BLOCK;
    int cstart = 0;
    while (numEntries > 1) {
        int prevStart = cstart;
        cstart += numEntries;
        numEntries /= 2;
        if (idx < numEntries) {
            int i1 = idx * 2 + prevStart;
            tmpCounts[idx + cstart] = tmpCounts[i1] + tmpCounts[i1 + 1];
        }
        __syncthreads();
    }
    if (idx == 0) {
        dumbCounts[cstart] = tmpCounts[cstart];
        tmpCounts[cstart] = 0;
    }
    while (cstart > 0) {
        int prevStart = cstart;
        cstart -= numEntries * 2;
        if (idx < numEntries) {
            int v1 = tmpCounts[idx + prevStart];
            int i1 = idx * 2 + cstart;
            tmpCounts[i1 + 1] = tmpCounts[i1] + v1;
            tmpCounts[i1] = v1;
            dumbCounts[i1] = dumbCounts[i1 + 1] = dumbCounts[idx + prevStart];
        }
        numEntries *= 2;
        __syncthreads();
    }
    if (start + idx < stop) {
        isPrime[start + idx] = tmpCounts[idx];
        addend[start + idx] = dumbCounts[idx];
    }
}

__global__ void createCounts(int* isPrime, int* addend, int lb, int ub) {
    int step = gridDim.x * THREADS_PER_BLOCK;
    for (int i = lb + blockIdx.x * THREADS_PER_BLOCK; i < ub; i += step) {
        int start = i;
        int stop = min(i + step, ub);
        makeCounts(isPrime, addend, start, stop);
    }
}

__global__ void sumCounts(int* isPrime, int* addend, int lb, int ub,
        int* totalsum) {
    int idx = blockIdx.x;
    int s = 0;
    for (int i = lb + idx; i < ub; i += THREADS_PER_BLOCK) {
        isPrime[i] += s;
        s += addend[i];
    }
    if (idx == 0) {
        *totalsum = s;
    }
}

__global__ void condensePrimes(int* isPrime, int* primeList, int lb, int ub,
        int primeStartInd, int primeCount) {
    int idx = blockIdx.x * THREADS_PER_BLOCK + threadIdx.x;
    int step = gridDim.x * THREADS_PER_BLOCK;
    for (int i = lb + idx; i < ub; i += step) {
        int term = isPrime[i];
        int nextTerm = i + 1 == ub ? primeCount : isPrime[i + 1];
        if (term < nextTerm) {
            primeList[primeStartInd + term] = i;
        }
    }
}

int main(void) {
    printf("Enter upper bound:\n");
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);

    int *isPrime, *addend, *numPrimes, *primeList;
    cudaError_t t = cudaMalloc((void**) &isPrime, n * sizeof(int));
    assert(t == cudaSuccess);
    t = cudaMalloc(&addend, n * sizeof(int));
    assert(t == cudaSuccess);
    t = cudaMalloc(&numPrimes, sizeof(int));
    assert(t == cudaSuccess);
    int primeBound = 2 * n / log(n);
    t = cudaMalloc(&primeList, primeBound * sizeof(int));
    assert(t == cudaSuccess);
    int numBlocks = min(MAX_BLOCKS,
            (n + THREADS_PER_BLOCK - 1) / THREADS_PER_BLOCK);
    initialize<<<numBlocks, THREADS_PER_BLOCK>>>(isPrime, n);
    t = cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    assert(t == cudaSuccess);

    int bound = (int) ceil(sqrt(n));

    int lb;
    int ub = 2;
    int primeStartInd = 0;
    int primeEndInd = 0;

    while (ub < n) {
        if (primeEndInd > primeStartInd) {
            int lowprime;
            t = cudaMemcpy(&lowprime, primeList + primeStartInd, sizeof(int),
                    cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
            assert(t == cudaSuccess);
            int numcols = n / lowprime;
            int numrows = primeEndInd - primeStartInd;
            int threadx = min(numcols, THREADS_PER_BLOCK);
            int thready = min(numrows, THREADS_PER_BLOCK / threadx);
            int blockx = min(numcols / threadx, MAX_BLOCKS);
            int blocky = min(numrows / thready, MAX_BLOCKS / blockx);
            dim3 gridsize(blockx, blocky);
            dim3 blocksize(threadx, thready);
            clearMultiples<<<gridsize, blocksize>>>(isPrime, primeList,
                    primeStartInd, primeEndInd, n);
            t = cudaDeviceSynchronize();
            assert(t == cudaSuccess);
        }
        lb = ub;
        ub *= 2;
        if (lb >= bound) {
            ub = n;
        }
        numBlocks = min(MAX_BLOCKS,
                (ub - lb + THREADS_PER_BLOCK - 1) / THREADS_PER_BLOCK);

        createCounts<<<numBlocks, THREADS_PER_BLOCK>>>(isPrime, addend, lb, ub);
        t = cudaDeviceSynchronize();
        assert(t == cudaSuccess);

        sumCounts<<<THREADS_PER_BLOCK, 1>>>(isPrime, addend, lb, ub, numPrimes);
        t = cudaDeviceSynchronize();
        assert(t == cudaSuccess);

        int primeCount;
        t = cudaMemcpy(&primeCount, numPrimes, sizeof(int),
                cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
        assert(t == cudaSuccess);
        assert(primeCount > 0);

        primeStartInd = primeEndInd;
        primeEndInd += primeCount;
        condensePrimes<<<numBlocks, THREADS_PER_BLOCK>>>(isPrime, primeList, lb,
                ub, primeStartInd, primeCount);
        t = cudaDeviceSynchronize();
        assert(t == cudaSuccess);
    }
    int finalprimes[primeEndInd];
    t = cudaMemcpy(finalprimes, primeList, primeEndInd * sizeof(int),
            cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    assert(t == cudaSuccess);

    t = cudaFree(isPrime);
    assert(t == cudaSuccess);
    t = cudaFree(addend);
    assert(t == cudaSuccess);
    t = cudaFree(numPrimes);
    assert(t == cudaSuccess);
    t = cudaFree(primeList);
    assert(t == cudaSuccess);
    for (int i = 0; i < primeEndInd; i++) {
        if (i % 16 == 0)
            printf("\n");
        else
            printf(" ");
        printf("%4d", finalprimes[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your error checking is flawed.  What happens if you set THREADS_PER_BLOCK to 2000 (an illegal value), and enter 1000 for the upper bound?  Your program does not throw any errors. Consider using an error checking methodology such as I used [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15582684/cudamalloc-does-not-work-when-trying-to-create-a-custom-struct-type/15588551#15588551).  Alternatively, look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038589/what-is-the-canonical-way-to-check-for-errors-using-the-cuda-runtime-api), and notice the difference  with your approach in trapping kernel errors.

Comment: SO doesn't really work well with big, rambling questions like this.  There are any number of things in your question I could respond to, but I can't really post an answer since I can't be sure it would answer all of your several questions.  At least 3 of your questions could easily be broken out into separate, crisp SO questions that could be crisply answered, with little uncertainty.  Instead this overloaded question is constipated.  Voting to close as not a real question.  A real question is crisp, answerable, and singular.

Comment: Where can I ask a question about general help with optimization?  The problem I'm having is that I don't know what I should be asking.  I know that there are ways I could improve my code, but I don't know enough about CUDA to find something specific to ask.  A lot of the literature that's out there is vague and contradictory and generally doesn't seem to apply.

Comment: I'm not suggesting you go somewhere else with your questions.  I'm suggesting you restructure them to simplify, focus, and singularize your questions.   Post several if you need to.  If you need general information on CUDA optimization, the [NVIDIA webinar page](https://developer.nvidia.com/gpu-computing-webinars) has a variety of good resources.

Answer (score 1):

Answering some of your questions.

1. Fix your error checking as defined in the comments.
2. define what you mean by "concurrent reads".  You're concerned about this but I'm not sure what you mean by it.

> Is it necessary to call synchronize after every kernel call?

No, it isn't.  If your code is not working correctly, synchronizing after every kernel call then doing proper error checking will tell you if any kernels are not launching correctly.  Synchronization is generally not needed for relatively simple single-stream programs like this one.  The cuda calls that need to synchronize like cudaMemcpy will do this automatically for you.

> Do I need to synchronize after memcpy's as well?

No, cudaMemcpy is synchronous in nature (it will force all cuda calls in the same stream to complete before it begins, and it will not return control to the host thread until the copy is complete.)  If you don't want the blocking characteristic (not returning control to the host thread until complete) then you can use the cudaMemcpyAsync version of the call.  You would use streams to get around the behavior of forcing all previous cuda calls to complete.

> Finally, how come when I set THREADS_PER_BLOCK to 512 it doesn't work?

Please define what you mean by "it doesn't work".  I compiled your code with THREADS_PER_BLOCK of 512 and 256, and for an upper bound of 1000 it gave the same output in each case.