# Thrust device_malloc and device_new

Tags: cuda, thrust

What are the advantages for using Thrust `device_malloc` instead of the normal `cudaMalloc` and what does `device_new` do?

For `device_malloc` it seems the only reason to use it is that it's just a bit cleaner.

The `device_new` documentation says:

> "device_new implements the placement new operator for types resident
>   in device memory. device_new calls T's null constructor on a array of
>   objects in device memory. No memory is allocated by this function."

Which I don't understand...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`device_malloc` returns the proper type of object if you plan on using Thrust for other things. There is normally no reason to use `cudaMalloc` if you are using Thrust. Encapsulating CUDA calls makes it easier and usually cleaner. The same thing goes for C++ and STL containers versus C-style arrays and `malloc`.

For `device_new`, you should read the following line of the [documentation](http://thrust.github.io/doc/group__allocation__functions.html#ga4c8a057314da6f7dab0b471f5b726247):

```cpp
 template<typename T>
 device_ptr<T> thrust::device_new (device_ptr< void > p, const size_t n = 1)
```

> p: A device_ptr to a region of device memory into which to construct
>   one or many Ts.

Basically, this function can be used if memory has already been allocated. Only the default constructor will be called, and this will return a `device_pointer` casted to T's type.

On the other hand, the following method allocates memory and returns a `device_ptr<T>`:

```cpp
template<typename T >
device_ptr<T> thrust::device_new (const size_t n = 1)
```

Comment: Cheers, I wonder why no one pointed out that I can use thrust device_new when [I posted a question about copying an object to device memory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16024087/copy-an-object-to-device) !
I understand that I still have to copy the fields inside manually, but the first step (copying the object itself) better be done with thrust..

Comment: Well, everyone does not use Thrust. For simple things, you do not need it, but it makes your code much clearer and readable for non-CUDA developers. It is a good thing to know how to do things without Thrust though, else you may be lost once you start debugging your code.

Answer (score 1):

So I think I found out one good use for device_new

It's basically a better way of initialising an object and copying it to the device, while holding a pointer to it on host.

so instead of doing:

```
Particle *dev_p;
cudaMalloc((void**)&(dev_p), sizeof(Particle));
cudaMemcpy(dev_p, &p, sizeof(Particle), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

test2<<<1,1>>>(dev_p);
```

I can just do:

```
thrust::device_ptr<Particle> p = thrust::device_new<Particle>(1);
test2<<<1,1>>>(thrust::raw_pointer_cast(p));
```