# how to allocate memory for arrays of structure of arrays

Tags: c++, cuda, malloc

So I have a `struct` as shown below, I would like to create an array of that structure and allocate memory for it (using `malloc`).

```
typedef struct {
    float *Dxx;
    float *Dxy;
    float *Dyy;
} Hessian;
```

My first instinct was to allocate memory for the whole structure, but then, I believe the internal arrays (`Dxx`, `Dxy`, `Dyy`) won't be assigned. If I assign internal arrays one by one, then the structure of arrays would be undefined. Now I think I should assign memory for internal arrays and then for the structure array, but it seems just wrong to me. How should I solve this issue?

I require a logic for using `malloc` in this situation instead of `new` / `delete` because I have to do this in [cuda](/questions/tagged/cuda) and memory allocation in [cuda](/questions/tagged/cuda) is done using `cudaMalloc`, which is somewhat similar to `malloc`.

Comment: You solve the issue by learning how to use `std::vector`, and letting the C++ library to do the work for you. See your C++ book for more information.

Comment: Don't.  Make those members `std::vector`s and then have a `std::vector ` of those structs.

Comment: First of all never use `malloc` in C++. Secondly, why not use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)? Or maybe even [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) if the size is fixed and known at compile-time?

Comment: Suppose you had only *one* `Hessian`. How would you construct its member arrays? Now what if you had *two* of them? You seem to be making at least one false assumption about memory management.

Comment: You don't need `typedef struct` in C++.

Comment: That's a structure of pointers, not of arrays.

Comment: Of course you can do this in a number of ways, but using an array of these structures in CUDA will be somewhat complicated and may not be the way to achieve best performance.  Anyway [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16024087/copy-an-object-to-device) is a worked example in CUDA of allocating and using an array of structures, where the structure has an embedded pointer.

Comment: I've added another approach to solve your issue.

Answer (score 3):

In C++ you should not use `malloc` at all and instead use `new` and `delete` if actually necessary. From the information you've provided it is not, because in C++ you also rather use `std::vector` (or `std::array`) over C-style-arrays. Also the `typedef` is not needed.

So I'd suggest rewriting your struct to use vectors and then generate a vector of this struct, i.e.:

```
struct Hessian {
  std::vector<float> Dxx;
  std::vector<float> Dxy;
  std::vector<float> Dyy;
}; 

std::vector<Hessian> hessianArray(2); // vector containing two instances of your struct
hessianArray[0].Dxx.push_back(1.0); // example accessing the members
```

Using vectors you do not have to worry about allocation most of the time, since the class handles that for you. Every `Hessian` contained in `hessianArray` is automatically allocated for you, stored on the heap and destroyed when `hessianArray` goes out of scope.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like problem which could be solved using STL container. Regarding the fact you *won't* know sizes of arrays you may use `std::vector`.

It's less error-prone, easier to maintain/work with and standard containers **free their resources them self** ([RAII](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2321511/what-is-meant-by-resource-acquisition-is-initialization-raii)). @muXXmit2X already shown how to use them.

But if you have/want to use dynamic allocation, you have to first allocate space for array of X structures

```
Hessian *h = new Hessian[X];
```

Then allocate space for all arrays in all structures

```
for (int i = 0; i < X; i++)
{
    h[i].Dxx = new float[Y];
    // Same for Dxy & Dyy
}
```

Now you can access and modify them. Also dont forget to free resources

```
for (int i = 0; i < X; i++)
{
    delete[] h[i].Dxx;
    // Same for Dxy & Dyy
}
delete[] h;
```

---

You should **never** use malloc in [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b).

Why?

`new` will ensure that your type will have their constructor called. While `malloc` will not call constructor. The `new` keyword is also more type safe whereas `malloc` is **not** typesafe at all.

Comment: _It will ensure that your type will have their constructor called._ You mean `new`, right? The way you wrote it, it sounds like `malloc` would call the constructor, which it doesn't.

Comment: Migh be a bit misleading. Ive fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

As other answers point out, the use of `malloc` (or even `new`) should be avoided in [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b). Anyway, as you requested:

> I require a logic for using `malloc` in this situation instead of `new` / `delete` because I have to do this in [cuda](/questions/tagged/cuda)...

In this case you have to allocate memory for the `Hessian` instances first, then iterate throug them and allocate memory for each `Dxx`, `Dxy` and `Dyy`. I would create a function for this like follows:

```
Hessian* create(size_t length) {
    Hessian* obj = (Hessian*)malloc(length * sizeof(Hessian));

    for(size_t i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
        obj[i].Dxx = (float*)malloc(sizeof(float));
        obj[i].Dxy = (float*)malloc(sizeof(float));
        obj[i].Dyy = (float*)malloc(sizeof(float));
    }

    return obj;
}
```

To deallocate the memory you allocated with `create` function above, you have to iterate through `Hessian` instances and deallocate each `Dxx`, `Dxy` and `Dyy` first, then deallocate the block which stores the `Hessian` instances:

```
void destroy(Hessian* obj, size_t length) {
    for(size_t i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
        free(obj[i].Dxx);
        free(obj[i].Dxy);
        free(obj[i].Dyy);
    }

    free(obj);
}
```

**Note:** using the presented method will pass the responsibility of preventing memory leaks to you.

---

If you wish to use the [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead of manual allocation and deallocation (which is highly recommended), you can [write a custom allocator](http://jrruethe.github.io/blog/2015/11/22/allocators/) for it to use `cudaMalloc` and `cudaFree` like follows:

```
template<typename T> struct cuda_allocator {
    using value_type = T;

    cuda_allocator() = default;
    template<typename U> cuda_allocator(const cuda_allocator<U>&) {
    }

    T* allocate(std::size_t count) {
        if(count <= max_size()) {
            void* raw_ptr = nullptr;

            if(cudaMalloc(&raw_ptr, count * sizeof(T)) == cudaSuccess)
                return static_cast<T*>(raw_ptr);
        }
        throw std::bad_alloc();
    }
    void deallocate(T* raw_ptr, std::size_t) {
        cudaFree(raw_ptr);
    }
    static std::size_t max_size() {
        return std::numeric_limits<std::size_t>::max() / sizeof(T);
    }
};

template<typename T, typename U>
inline bool operator==(const cuda_allocator<T>&, const cuda_allocator<U>&) {
    return true;
}
template<typename T, typename U>
inline bool operator!=(const cuda_allocator<T>& a, const cuda_allocator<U>& b) {
    return !(a == b);
}
```

The usage of an custom allocator is very simple, you just have to specify it as second template parameter of `std::vector`:

```
struct Hessian {
    std::vector<float, cuda_allocator<float>> Dxx;
    std::vector<float, cuda_allocator<float>> Dxy;
    std::vector<float, cuda_allocator<float>> Dyy;
};

/* ... */

std::vector<Hessian, cuda_allocator<Hessian>> hessian;
```