# CUDA, dynamic array + array. malloc and copy

Tags: arrays, dynamic, cuda

So I have been stuck on this problem for a while. My struct looks like this:

```
typedef struct 
{
int size;
int dim[DIMENSIONS];
float *data;

}matrix;
```

Now the problem for me is how to malloc and memcpy. This is how I'm doing it:

```
matrix * d_in;
matrix * d_out;
const int THREADS_BYTES = sizeof(int) + sizeof(int)*DIMENSIONS + sizeof(float)*h_A->_size;
cudaMalloc((void **) &d_in, THREADS_BYTES);
cudaMemcpy(d_in, h_A, THREADS_BYTES, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
```

EDIT: this is how I allocated h_a:

```
 matrix  A; // = (matrix*)malloc(sizeof(matrix));
 A._dim[0] = 40;
 A._dim[1] = 60;
 A._size = A._dim[0]*A._dim[1];
 A._data = (float*)malloc(A._size*sizeof(float));
 matrix *h_A = &A;
```

Where h_A is a matrix I allocated. I call my kernel like this:

```
DeviceComp<<<gridSize, blockSize>>>(d_out, d_in);
```

However, in my kernel I cannot reach any data from the struct, only the array and the variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a common problem.  When you did the malloc operation on the host (for h_a->data), you allocated host data, which is not accessible from the device.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15431365/cudamemcpy-segmentation-fault/15435592#15435592) describes in some detail what is going on and how to fix it.

In your case, something like this should work:

```
matrix  A; // = (matrix*)malloc(sizeof(matrix));
A._dim[0] = 40;
A._dim[1] = 60;
A._size = A._dim[0]*A._dim[1];
A._data = (float*)malloc(A._size*sizeof(float));
matrix *h_A = &A; 

float *d_data;
cudaMalloc((void **) &d_data, A._size*sizeof(float));


matrix * d_in;
matrix * d_out;
const int THREADS_BYTES = sizeof(int) + sizeof(int)*DIMENSIONS + sizeof(float)*h_A->_size;
cudaMalloc((void **) &d_in, THREADS_BYTES);
cudaMemcpy(d_in, h_A, THREADS_BYTES, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

cudaMemcpy(&(d_in->data), &d_data, sizeof(float *), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
```

Note that this doesn't actually copy the `data` area from the host copy of `A` to the device copy.  It simply makes a device-accessible `data` area, equal in size to the host `data` area.  If you also want to copy the `data` area, that will require another `cudaMemcpy` operation, using `h_a->data` and `d_data`.