# Pass double pointer in a struct to CUDA

Tags: pointers, memory-management, struct, cuda

I've got the following struct:

```
 struct Param
{
double** K_RP;                              
};
```

And I wanna perform the following operations on "K_RP" in CUDA

```
 __global__  void Test( struct Param prop)
       {
       int ix = threadIdx.x;
       int iy = threadIdx.y;
       prop.K_RP[ix][iy]=2.0;
       }
```

If "prop" has the following form, how should I do my "cudaMalloc" and "cudaMemcpy" operations?

```
int main( )
{
Param prop;
Param cuda_prop;

prop.K_RP=alloc2D(Imax,Jmax);

//cudaMalloc cuda_prop ?

//cudaMemcpyH2D prop to cuda_prop ?

Test<<< (1,1), (Imax,Jmax)>>> ( cuda_prop);   

//cudaMemcpyD2H cuda_prop to prop ?

return (0);

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Questions like this get asked from time to time.  If you search on the cuda tag, you'll find a variety of examples with answers.    Here's [one example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16539085/cuda-dynamic-array-array-malloc-and-copy/16545272#16545272).

- In general, dynamically allocated data contained within structures or other objects requires special handling.  This [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15431365/cudamemcpy-segmentation-fault/15435592#15435592) explains why and how to do it for the single pointer (`*`) case.
- Handling double pointers (`**`) is difficult enough that most people would recommend "flattening" the storage so that it can be handled by reference with a single pointer (`*`).  If you really want to see how the double pointer (`**`) method works, review [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6137218/cuda-2d-array-problem).  It's not trivial.