# How to declare a struct with a dynamic array inside it in device

Tags: cuda

How to declare a struct in device that a member of it, is an array and then dynamically allocated memory for this. for example in below code, compiler said: `error : calling a __host__ function("malloc") from a __global__ function("kernel_ScoreMatrix") is not allowed`. is there another way for perform this action?

Type of`dev_size_idx_threads` is `int*` and value of it, sent to kernel and used for allocate memory.

```
struct struct_matrix
{
    int *idx_threads_x;
    int *idx_threads_y;
    int thread_diag_length;
    int idx_length;
};

struct  struct_matrix matrix[BLOCK_SIZE_Y];

matrix->idx_threads_x= (int *) malloc ((*(dev_size_idx_threads) * sizeof(int) ));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From device code, dynamic memory allocations (`malloc` and `new`) are supported [only with devices of cc2.0 and greater](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#dynamic-global-memory-allocation-and-operations).  If you have a cc2.0 device or greater, and you pass an appropriate flag to nvcc (such as `-arch=sm_20`) you should not see this error.  Note that if you are passing multiple compilation targets (sm_10, sm_20, etc.), if even one of the targets does not meet the cc2.0+ requirement, you will see this error.

If you have a cc1.x device, you will need to perform these types of allocations from the host (e.g. using `cudaMalloc`) and pass appropriate pointers to your kernel.

If you choose that route (allocating from the host), you may also be interested in my answer to questions like this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16815705/passing-an-struct-including-a-pointer-to-another-struct-to-kernel-in-cuda).

**EDIT:** responding to questions below:

1. In visual studio (2008 express, should be similar for other versions), you can set the compilation target as follows: open project, select Project...Properties, select Configuration Properties...CUDA Runtime API...GPU  Now, on the right hand pane, you will see entries like `GPU Architecture (1)` (and `(2)` etc.)  These are drop-downs that you can click on and select the target(s) you want to compile for.  If your GPU is sm_21 I would select that for `(1)` and leave the others blank, or select compatible versions like sm_20.
2. To see worked examples, please follow the link I gave above.  A couple worked examples are linked from my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15431365/cudamemcpy-segmentation-fault/15435592#15435592) as well as a description of how it is done.

Comment: Thank you. my device CC is 2.1 , How to can set this parameter in Nsight visual studio? for allocating from the host, can you show a simple example?

Comment: I found an answer for change `sm` parameter in [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14411435/how-to-set-cuda-compiler-flags-in-visual-studio-2010)