# Pass host pointer array to device global memory pointer array?

Tags: memory-management, cuda

Suppose we have;

```
struct collapsed {
    char **seq;
    int num;
};
...
__device__ *collapsed xdev;
...

collapsed *x_dev

cudaGetSymbolAddress((void **)&x_dev, xdev);
cudaMemcpyToSymbol(x_dev, x, sizeof(collapsed)*size); //x already defined collapsed * , this line gives ERROR
```

Whay do you think I am getting error at the last line `: invalid device symbol` ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first problem here is that `x_dev` isn't a device symbol. It might contain an address in a device memory, but that address cannot be passed to `cudaMemcpyToSymbol`. The call should just be:

```
cudaMemcpyToSymbol(xdev, ......);
```

Which brings up the second problem. Doing this:

```
cudaMemcpyToSymbol(xdev, x, sizeof(collapsed)*size);
```

would be illegal. `xdev` is a pointer, so the only valid value you can copy to `xdev` is a device address. If `x` is the address of a  `struct collapsed` in device memory, then the only valid version of this memory transfer operation is

```
cudaMemcpyToSymbol(xdev, &x, sizeof(collapsed *));
```

ie. `x` must have previously have been set to the address of memory allocated in the device, something like

```
collapsed *x;
cudaMalloc((void **)&x, sizeof(collapsed)*size);
cudaMemcpy(x, host_src, sizeof(collapsed)*size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
```

---

As promised, here is a complete working example. First the code:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>

struct collapsed {
    char **seq;
    int num;
};

__device__ collapsed xdev;

__global__
void kernel(const size_t item_sz)
{
    if (threadIdx.x < xdev.num) {
        char *p = xdev.seq[threadIdx.x];
        char val = 0x30 + threadIdx.x;
        for(size_t i=0; i<item_sz; i++) {
            p[i] = val;
        }
    }
}

#define gpuQ(ans) { gpu_assert((ans), __FILE__, __LINE__); }
void gpu_assert(cudaError_t code, const char *file, const int line)
{
    if (code != cudaSuccess)
    {
        std::cerr << "gpu_assert: " << cudaGetErrorString(code) << " " 
            << file << " " << line << std::endl;
        exit(code);
    }
}

int main(void)
{

    const int nitems = 32;
    const size_t item_sz = 16;
    const size_t buf_sz = size_t(nitems) * item_sz;

    // Gpu memory for sequences
    char *_buf;
    gpuQ( cudaMalloc((void **)&_buf, buf_sz) );
    gpuQ( cudaMemset(_buf, 0x7a, buf_sz) );

    // Host array for holding sequence device pointers
    char **seq = new char*[nitems];
    size_t offset = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<nitems; i++, offset += item_sz) {
        seq[i] = _buf + offset;
    }

    // Device array holding sequence pointers
    char **_seq;
    size_t seq_sz =  sizeof(char*) * size_t(nitems);
    gpuQ( cudaMalloc((void **)&_seq, seq_sz) );
    gpuQ( cudaMemcpy(_seq, seq, seq_sz, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice) );

    // Host copy of the xdev structure to copy to the device
    collapsed xdev_host;
    xdev_host.num = nitems;
    xdev_host.seq = _seq;

    // Copy to device symbol
    gpuQ( cudaMemcpyToSymbol(xdev, &xdev_host, sizeof(collapsed)) );

    // Run Kernel
    kernel<<<1,nitems>>>(item_sz);

    // Copy back buffer
    char *buf = new char[buf_sz];
    gpuQ( cudaMemcpy(buf, _buf, buf_sz, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost) );

    // Print out seq values
    // Each string should be ASCII starting from ´0´ (0x30)
    char *seq_vals = buf; 
    for(int i=0; i<nitems; i++, seq_vals += item_sz) {
        std::string s;
        s.append(seq_vals, item_sz);
        std::cout << s << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

and here it is compiled and run:

```
$ /usr/local/cuda/bin/nvcc -arch=sm_12 -Xptxas=-v -g -G -o erogol erogol.cu 
./erogol.cu(19): Warning: Cannot tell what pointer points to, assuming global memory space
ptxas info    : 8 bytes gmem, 4 bytes cmem[14]
ptxas info    : Compiling entry function '_Z6kernelm' for 'sm_12'
ptxas info    : Used 5 registers, 20 bytes smem, 4 bytes cmem[1]

$ /usr/local/cuda/bin/cuda-memcheck ./erogol 
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
0000000000000000
1111111111111111
2222222222222222
3333333333333333
4444444444444444
5555555555555555
6666666666666666
7777777777777777
8888888888888888
9999999999999999
::::::::::::::::
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
================
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
????????????????
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC
DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD
EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE
FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
GGGGGGGGGGGGGGGG
HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH
IIIIIIIIIIIIIIII
JJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJ
KKKKKKKKKKKKKKKK
LLLLLLLLLLLLLLLL
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN
OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
```

Some notes:

1. To simplify things a bit, I have only used a single memory allocation `_buf` to hold all of the string data. Each value of `seq` is set to a different address within `_buf`. This is functionally equivalent to running a separate `cudaMalloc` call for each pointer, but much faster.
2. The key concept is to assemble a copy of the structure you wish to access on the device *in host memory*, then copy that to the device. All of the pointers in my `xdev_host` are *device* pointers. The CUDA API doesn't have any sort of deep copy or automatic pointer translation facility, so it is the programmer's responsibility to make sure this is correct.
3. Each thread in the kernel just fills its sequence with a difference ASCII character. Note that I have declared my xdev as a structure, rather than pointer to structure and copy values rather than a reference to the `__device__` symbol (again to simplify things slightly). But otherwise the sequence of operations is what you would need to make your design pattern work.
4. Because I only have access to a compute 1.x device, the compiler issues a warning. One compute 2.x and 3.x this won't happen because of the improved memory model in those devices. The warning is normal and can be safely ignored.
5. Because each sequence is just written into a different part of `_buf`, I can transfer all the sequences back to the host with a single cudaMemcpy call.

Comment: However x_dev is pointing to device right? Also if I change x_dev to xdev it still not work. If I choose the way you suggest, it does not pass the internal char pointer of pointer to device. It only passes the struct pointer.

Comment: @Erogol: Yes, x_dev is a device *address*, but it isn't a device *symbol*. They are not the same.  As for your "doesn't work" comment, that is because you are (I presume) expecting some automagical deep copy of that structure, but CUDA doesn't support deep copying. You need to manually allocate and copy the nested pointers on the device first. There are many [SO] questions which have examples of how to do this if you care to read them.

Comment: I really read all of them but still cannot do that. The char** at collapsed structure breaks the usage of all examples in the StackOverflow.

Comment: @Erogol: If you can give me a couple of hours, I will try and put together a full working example of a deep copy and add it to the answer. But as it stands, the answer is completely correct, I would appreciate it if you would accept it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16815705/passing-an-struct-including-a-pointer-to-another-struct-to-kernel-in-cuda is my initial question and the exact structure hierarchy is like in the question. I have one statically defined 'data X' and I am trying dozens of different approach to succeed it but nothing actually work.