# Write access violation allocating memory for nested data structure on GPU using CUDA C/C++

Tags: c++, memory-management, cuda, dynamic-memory-allocation

I have the following data structure:

```c
typedef struct
{
    float var1;
    signed short var2;
    float var3[4];
    float var4[3];
    float var5[3];
    float var6;
} B;

typedef struct
{
    signed long num_objects;
    signed long max_objects;
    B* objects;
} A;
```

I would like to allocate memory for data structure `A` and its element `B*` objects. I am doing it in the following way:

```cpp
A* deviceOutputData = nullptr;
B* deviceOutputDataObject = nullptr;
cudaDeviceSynchronize();
cudaError_t cudaStatus = cudaMalloc(&deviceOutputData, sizeof(A));
cudaDeviceSynchronize();
if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
    fprintf(stderr, "cudaMalloc for deviceOutputData failed: %s\n", cudaGetErrorString(cudaStatus));
}
cudaDeviceSynchronize();
cudaStatus = cudaMalloc(&deviceOutputDataObject, sizeof(B) * max_objectsA);
cudaDeviceSynchronize();
if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
    fprintf(stderr, "cudaMalloc for deviceOutputDataObject failed: %s\n", cudaGetErrorString(cudaStatus));
    cudaFree(deviceOutputData);
}
else {
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    deviceOutputData->objects = deviceOutputDataObject;
}
```

**But** I am getting write access violation when I do

```cpp
deviceOutputData->objects = deviceOutputDataObject;
```

Can anyone help me solve this issue?

I have tried the above code and I am expecting to successfully allocate memory for both `A` and `B` and link `B` address with `A` address of the data structure.

Comment: `deviceOutputData->objects` dereferences `deviceOutputData` on the host, but it's not a valid host pointer. You need to copy the value into device memory.

Comment: Hi, thanks alot for your response, how can I copy the value into device memory ? i am stuck in this issue since long time without any help :((

Comment: Create an `A`, fill in its members, then `cudaMemcpy` it to the memory you allocated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15431365/cudamemcpy-segmentation-fault/15435592#15435592