# Memory allocation on GPU for dynamic array of structs

Tags: c, struct, cuda, dynamic-memory-allocation

I have problem with passing array of struct to gpu kernel. I based on this topic - [cudaMemcpy segmentation fault](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15431365/cudamemcpy-segmentation-fault) and I wrote sth like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Test {
    char *array;
};

__global__ void kernel(Test *dev_test) {
    for(int i=0; i < 5; i++) {
        printf("Kernel[0][i]: %c \n", dev_test[0].array[i]);
    }
}

int main(void) {

    int n = 4, size = 5;
    Test *dev_test, *test;

    test = (Test*)malloc(sizeof(Test)*n);
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        test[i].array = (char*)malloc(size * sizeof(char));

    for(int i=0; i < n; i++) {
        char temp[] = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' , 'e' };
        memcpy(test[i].array, temp, size * sizeof(char));
    }

    cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_test, n * sizeof(Test));
    cudaMemcpy(dev_test, test, n * sizeof(Test), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    for(int i=0; i < n; i++) {
        cudaMalloc((void**)&(test[i].array), size * sizeof(char));
        cudaMemcpy(&(dev_test[i].array), &(test[i].array), size * sizeof(char), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    }

    kernel<<<1, 1>>>(dev_test);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();

    //  memory free
    return 0;
}
```

There is no error, but displayed values in kernel are incorrect. What I'm doing wrong? Thank in advance for any help.

Comment: Why is it `cudaMalloc((void**)&(test[i].array), size * sizeof(char));` and not `cudaMalloc((void**)&(dev_test[i].array), size * sizeof(char));` ? Also, it should be `cudaMemcpy(dev_test[i].array, test[i].array, size * sizeof(char), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);`.

Comment: @francis, it doesn't works (Segmentation fault (core dumped)). On gpu we can't allocate memory in standard way.

Comment: Additional friendly advice : do not pick code from a question except if you have understood the problem faced by the asker...Sorry if my suggestion didn't work. My suggestion was to allocate memory for `dev_test[i].array`, not for `test[i].array` which is already allocated on the CPU by `test[i].array = (char*)malloc(size * sizeof(char));`.

Comment: @francis, ok no problem. Yes `test[i].array` is already allocated but only on CPU, no on GPU. We can't allocate memory for `dev_test[i].array`, because this memory is only visible from device. At least I understand it so.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. This is allocating a new pointer to host memory:

   ```
    test[i].array = (char*)malloc(size * sizeof(char));
   ```
2. This is copying data to that region in host memory:

   ```
    memcpy(test[i].array, temp, size * sizeof(char));
   ```
3. This is *overwriting* the previously allocated pointer to host memory (from step 1 above) with a *new* pointer to device memory:

   ```
    cudaMalloc((void**)&(test[i].array), size * sizeof(char));
   ```

After step 3, the data you set up in step 2 is entirely lost, and no longer accessible in any fashion.  Referring to steps 3 and 4 in the [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15431365/cudamemcpy-segmentation-fault) you linked:

> 3.Create a separate int pointer on the host, let's call it `myhostptr`
>
> 4.cudaMalloc int storage on the device for `myhostptr`

You haven't done this.  You did not create a separate pointer.  You reused (erased, overwrote) an existing pointer, which was pointing to data you cared about on the host.  [This question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14284964/cuda-how-to-allocate-memory-for-data-member-of-a-class), also linked from the answer you linked, gives almost exactly the steps you need to follow, *in code*.

Here's a modified version of your code, which properly implements the missing steps 3 and 4 (and 5) that you didn't implement correctly according to the  question/answer you linked: (refer to comments delineating steps 3,4,5)

```
$ cat t755.cu
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Test {
    char *array;
};

__global__ void kernel(Test *dev_test) {
    for(int i=0; i < 5; i++) {
        printf("Kernel[0][i]: %c \n", dev_test[0].array[i]);
    }
}

int main(void) {

    int n = 4, size = 5;
    Test *dev_test, *test;

    test = (Test*)malloc(sizeof(Test)*n);
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        test[i].array = (char*)malloc(size * sizeof(char));

    for(int i=0; i < n; i++) {
        char temp[] = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' , 'e' };
        memcpy(test[i].array, temp, size * sizeof(char));
    }

    cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_test, n * sizeof(Test));
    cudaMemcpy(dev_test, test, n * sizeof(Test), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    // Step 3:
    char *temp_data[n];
    // Step 4:
    for (int i=0; i < n; i++)
      cudaMalloc(&(temp_data[i]), size*sizeof(char));
    // Step 5:
    for (int i=0; i < n; i++)
      cudaMemcpy(&(dev_test[i].array), &(temp_data[i]), sizeof(char *), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    // now copy the embedded data:
    for (int i=0; i < n; i++)
      cudaMemcpy(temp_data[i], test[i].array, size*sizeof(char), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    kernel<<<1, 1>>>(dev_test);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();

    //  memory free
    return 0;
}

$ nvcc -o t755 t755.cu
$ cuda-memcheck ./t755
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
Kernel[0][i]: a
Kernel[0][i]: b
Kernel[0][i]: c
Kernel[0][i]: d
Kernel[0][i]: e
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
$
```

Since the above methodology can be challenging for beginners, the usual advice is not to do it, but instead *flatten* your data structures.  Flatten generally means to rearrange the data storage so as to remove the embedded pointers that have to be separately allocated.

A trivial example of flattening this data structure would be to use this instead:

```
struct Test {
    char array[5];
};
```

It's recognized of course that this *particular* approach would not serve every purpose, but it should illustrate the general idea/intent.  With that modification, as an example, the code becomes much simpler:

```
$ cat t755.cu
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Test {
    char array[5];
};

__global__ void kernel(Test *dev_test) {
    for(int i=0; i < 5; i++) {
        printf("Kernel[0][i]: %c \n", dev_test[0].array[i]);
    }
}

int main(void) {

    int n = 4, size = 5;
    Test *dev_test, *test;

    test = (Test*)malloc(sizeof(Test)*n);

    for(int i=0; i < n; i++) {
        char temp[] = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' , 'e' };
        memcpy(test[i].array, temp, size * sizeof(char));
    }

    cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_test, n * sizeof(Test));
    cudaMemcpy(dev_test, test, n * sizeof(Test), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    kernel<<<1, 1>>>(dev_test);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();

    //  memory free
    return 0;
}
$ nvcc -o t755 t755.cu
$ cuda-memcheck ./t755
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
Kernel[0][i]: a
Kernel[0][i]: b
Kernel[0][i]: c
Kernel[0][i]: d
Kernel[0][i]: e
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
$
```

Comment: thanks a lot. What do you mean by "flatten your data structures"?

Comment: updated my answer to respond to this question.  However if you search on the CUDA tag you will find many references and examples for "flattening".

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @Robert Crovella for the answer. The above answer was very useful to me. I have updated the code from using charcter array to using integer array of structures for reference. In the kernel, values are updated and returned back to host.

```
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <stdlib.h>

  struct Test {
  int *array;
  };

  __global__ void kernel(Test *dev_test) {
  //    for(int i=0; i < 4; i++)
  //      for(int j=0; j < 5; j++) {
  //        printf("Kernel[X][i]: %d \n", dev_test[i].array[j]);
  //    }
  int i =threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x*blockDim.x;
  int j = threadIdx.y + blockIdx.y*blockDim.y;

  if(i<4 && j<5)
      dev_test[i].array[j] *= 2; 
  }

  int main(void) {

  int n = 4, size = 5;
  Test *dev_test, *test;

  test = (Test*)malloc(sizeof(Test)*n);
  for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
      test[i].array = (int*)malloc(size * sizeof(int));

  for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
      for(int j=0; j<size; j++)
          test[i].array[j] = i*n+j;

  cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_test, n * sizeof(Test));
  cudaMemcpy(dev_test, test, n * sizeof(Test), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

  // Step 3:
  int *temp_data[n];
  // Step 4:
  for (int i=0; i < n; i++)
      cudaMalloc(&(temp_data[i]), size*sizeof(int));
  // Step 5:
  for (int i=0; i < n; i++)
      cudaMemcpy(&(dev_test[i].array), &(temp_data[i]), sizeof(int *), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  // now copy the embedded data:
  for (int i=0; i < n; i++)
      cudaMemcpy(temp_data[i], test[i].array, size*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

  dim3 threads(4,5);
  kernel<<<1, threads>>>(dev_test);
  cudaDeviceSynchronize();

  for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
      cudaMemcpy(test[i].array, temp_data[i], size*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

  for(int i=0;i <n;i++){
      for(int j=0;j<size;j++)
          printf("%d ",test[i].array[j]);
  printf("\n");
  }
  //  memory free
  return 0;
  }
```