# Synchronizing Statically Allocated Struct Instances between CPU and GPU

Tags: memory, struct, cuda, static-allocation

I have a struct that contains an array, and I want to copy the contents from an instance of that struct in CPU memory to another instance in GPU memory.

My question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30082991/memory-allocation-on-gpu-for-dynamic-array-of-structs). There are two big difference between this question and the one from the link:

1. I'm not using an array of structs. I just need one.
2. All instances of the struct are statically allocated.

In attempt to answer my own question, I tried modifying the code in the answer as follows:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define cudaCheckError() { \
    cudaError_t err = cudaGetLastError(); \
    if(err != cudaSuccess) { \
      printf("Cuda error: %s:%d: %s\n", __FILE__, __LINE__, cudaGetErrorString(err)); \
      exit(1); \
    } \
  }

struct Test {
    char array[5];
};

__global__ void kernel(Test *dev_test) {
    for(int i=0; i < 5; i++) {
        printf("Kernel[0][i]: %c \n", dev_test[0].array[i]);
    }
}

__device__ Test dev_test; //dev_test is now global, statically allocated, and one instance of the struct

int main(void) {

    int size = 5;
    Test test; //test is now statically allocated and one instance of the struct

    char temp[] = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' , 'e' };
    memcpy(test.array, temp, size * sizeof(char));

    cudaCheckError();
    cudaMemcpy(&dev_test, &test, sizeof(Test), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaCheckError();
    kernel<<<1, 1>>>(&dev_test);
    cudaCheckError();
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    cudaCheckError();

    //  memory free
    return 0;
}
```

But this code throws a runtime error:

```
Cuda error: HelloCUDA.cu:34: invalid argument
```

Is there a way to copy `test` into `dev_test`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using a statically allocated `__device__` variable:

1. We *don't* use the `cudaMemcpy` API.  We use the `cudaMemcpyToSymbol` (or `cudaMemcpyFromSymbol`) API
2. We *don't* pass `__device__` variables as kernel arguments.  They are at global scope. You just use them in your kernel code.

The following code has these issues addressed:

```
$ cat t10.cu
#include <stdio.h>

#define cudaCheckError() { \
    cudaError_t err = cudaGetLastError(); \
    if(err != cudaSuccess) { \
      printf("Cuda error: %s:%d: %s\n", __FILE__, __LINE__, cudaGetErrorString(err)); \
      exit(1); \
    } \
  }

struct Test {
    char array[5];
};

__device__ Test dev_test; //dev_test is now global, statically allocated, and one instance of the struct

__global__ void kernel() {
    for(int i=0; i < 5; i++) {
        printf("Kernel[0][i]: %c \n", dev_test.array[i]);
    }
}


int main(void) {

    int size = 5;
    Test test; //test is now statically allocated and one instance of the struct

    char temp[] = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' , 'e' };
    memcpy(test.array, temp, size * sizeof(char));

    cudaCheckError();
    cudaMemcpyToSymbol(dev_test, &test, sizeof(Test));
    cudaCheckError();
    kernel<<<1, 1>>>();
    cudaCheckError();
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    cudaCheckError();

    //  memory free
    return 0;
}
$ nvcc -o t10 t10.cu
$ cuda-memcheck ./t10
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
Kernel[0][i]: a
Kernel[0][i]: b
Kernel[0][i]: c
Kernel[0][i]: d
Kernel[0][i]: e
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
$
```

(your array usage in kernel code also didn't make sense.  `dev_test` is not an  array, therefore you cannot index into it: `dev_test[0]....`)